# NHibernate: does building the session factory involve connecting to the database?

Tags: nhibernate, database-connection, sessionfactory

Following a migration of a database to a new server, my working copy cannot connect to the database anymore. But I'm experiencing something I didn't expect. Whenever a page in the application attempts to connect to this database, an error occurs during building of the session factory, i.e. before any attempt by the ISession to explicitly connect (e.g. to load an entity).

Is this right? Why would building the session factory require connecting to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building the session factory does not necessarily connect to the database. I wrote an application which instantiates the session factory to create an sql file from mapping files when there isn't a database at all.

But you can advise the session factory to create the database by using a configuration like the following:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

I wouldn't do it in production, but it may be useful for unit tests. Check your project for such a configuration.

If there isn't such a configuration, check the error message if there is any useful information and take a look at the stack trace to see where it happens.

Answer (score 1):

When building a session factory, it caches lot's of queries, relashionship, metadata and so on. It also create/update the database if asked to do so. That's what I got by reading some code of the [SessionFactoryImpl](https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionFactoryImpl.cs) class.

Remember that the process of creating a session factory is very heavyweight and should be only done once per DataSource. If you think about this, it makes sense that it caches and bootstrap everything that is possible.

If you really want to know why it happens and what it does, I suggest you to download the source and debug it.

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware that building the session factory should only happen once in the application's lifetime. I'm in development so I'm running the app through the VS web server, hence the reason why the session factory is building frequently.

Comment: I'm not creating the database through the session factory so I'm still nonplussed as to why NH seems to be trying to connect to the database while the session factory is being built.

Answer (score 0):

There is another property that can cause database connection attempt when building session factory.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">keywords</property>
```

Default value 'keywords' causes a stack trace like this (with MySQL):

```
Exception Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
    at ..............
    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
    at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
    at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare()
    at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect, NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.IConnectionHelper)
    at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(NHibernate.Engine.ISessionFactoryImplementor)
    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration, NHibernate.Engine.IMapping, NHibernate.Cfg.Settings, NHibernate.Event.EventListeners)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
```

More information on this feature can be found [here](https://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/06/23/auto-quote-table-column-names.html).